# Opencv, can't get destroyAllWindows to work

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

OpenCV 4.5.4, C++ and Win10.

Probably my syntax doesn't compute with this, but can anyone spot a fix to my problem? I can get the usb webcam window to open and it shows the stream. But I cannot close it.

This opens the window but brings no image in stream at all:

```
cv::imshow("Smaller", resized_down);
int c = cv::waitKey(1);
if ((char)c == 'c')
    cv::destroyAllWindows();
    break;
```

This works better, it shows the image stream, but by pressing C, it only freezes the image:

```
cv::imshow("Smaller", resized_down);
int c = cv::waitKey(1);
if ((char)c == 'c')
    break;
```

Please, indicate if you need to see more of my code.

Comment: You should turn on all warnings when compiling. A good compiler should warn here about “misleading indentation”. This is because `break` is indented as if it were part of the `if` statement, but it is not.

Comment: It seems your code in a loop if  I am not wrong, if like that please the code with related lines please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your first code should work with this fix (break; is always executing in your code!):

```
cv::namedWindow(“Smaller”);
while(true){
…
cv::imshow("Smaller", resized_down);
int c = cv::waitKey(1);
if ((char)c == 'c'){
    cv::destroyAllWindows();
    break;
}
…
}
```